# Any suggestion how to manage RAW photos on a Ubuntu Desktop?

Tags: nautilus, filemanager, shotwell, photo-management, photo

I'm looking for a while for ideas to manage my original RAW (eg. `*.NEF` or `*.cr2`) photos on my Ubuntu Desktop. Right know I'm using [Shotwell](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Shotwell) for the Import and folder structure of my pictures but as the RAW takes up a lot of diskspace, I would like to move them to external backupdrive/cloud just for the case that I want to work again on them.

[image: nautilus example screenshot of raws and jpgs]

**Is there any handy solution to keep a folder structure like eg. from [Shotwell](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Shotwell) and just copy or move the RAWs to your disk when you need them?**

Comment: Have you considered using Darktable for managing RAW files (on an external drive in your case) and then exporting JPEGs of processed files to Shotwell? Workflow is like this: Camera > External drive > Darktable > Export JPEGs to folder > Import JPEGs to Shotwell.

Comment: @TomBrossman sounds like a good idea, as I'm using already Darktable for working on the RAWs. I'll try your described workflow. Add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it as an solution, if there is not any better idea nor script coming up...